# TextFormField or TextField with more buttons , multibuttons flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I'm new to flutter and I don't know how to do it, please tell me how to do it or a working option. because I've been trying for a very long time

https://sun9-east.userapi.com/sun9-18/s/v1/ig2/NhRxi0YKSHPdqxIaG37XCWUcygL--5igPancpM8aVbjVuZazevntosns_TcgcXzYaIZN37dpzHlCa7o9Hr41pz67.jpg?size=2142x482&quality=95&type=album

https://sun9-west.userapi.com/sun9-63/s/v1/ig2/IVIkAOvJzFSbBD5VsqgncEuhvZAq8D3EkMKSnzK8wXffnPiB2SvLE2Q2sUkNjvvJp9-fLYzh2Wp3PUv8mD6zBLVe.jpg?size=1550x949&quality=95&type=album

https://sun9-west.userapi.com/sun9-50/s/v1/ig2/WdrgTVpnxrH7mBUe1L3a3SvAepAIB4zxvl_CQKJim1O0JxddGe-qQN5JLiN-WfIcgecwXdwGGZ7UNHScnpP3TtN1.jpg?size=1578x239&quality=95&type=album

https://sun9-north.userapi.com/sun9-81/s/v1/ig2/ZQZqB1bibWQUseKiajkYuHETzNeTGSV1dc1D5IEHXiUlwuYS-Cebt9uT5VknD3xWBsXjLNkMiAk_siV287kUE0JG.jpg?size=2142x482&quality=95&type=album

```
   TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration())
```

Comment: Links you provide are not working, what exactly you want can you please make it more clear?

Comment: https://youtu.be/49C7GpGxO8M

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

There's no possible option in the `TextField` or any equivalent widget for user input.

You can easily replicate those interfaces with layout widgets like `Column` and `Row`. If there's a case where you want to overlay other widgets on the `TextField` then you can stack them using `Stack`.

Else, if you need more advanced editor-like features, you can refer to packages like [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill).